# What is Wrong with my Collections.sort?

Tags: java, queue

I am working on my final for school, and am running into a bit of an issue.
I have created different sorts for the user to sort the information, but I have been getting different errors. 
The main one being "The method sort(List, Comparator) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ApplicationList, ApplicationList.AgeComparator)". 
I do not know what this means, or how to fix it.

The code is as follows:

**ApplicationList.Java**;

```
import java.util.*;

public class ApplicationList implements Comparable<ApplicationList>
{
    /**
     * variables within the queue class
     */
    private int maxSize;
    private String[] queArray;
    private int front;
    private int rear;
    private int nItems;

    /**
     * This is the constructor
     */
    public ApplicationList(int size) {
        maxSize = size;
        queArray = new String[maxSize];
        front = 0;
        rear = -1;
        nItems = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Adds to the bottom of the queue, and determines if the queue is full
     */
    public void enqueue(String j) {
        if (isFull()) {
            System.out.println("Queue is full");
        } else {
            if (rear == maxSize - 1)
                rear = front - 1;

            queArray[rear + 1]=j;
            rear++;
            nItems++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * dequeues items from the top of the queue
     */
    public String dequeue() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Queue is empty");
            return null;
        } else {
            String j = queArray[front];
            front++;
            if (front == maxSize)
                front = 0;

            nItems--;
            return j;
        }
    }

    /**
     * peeks at the front of the queue
     */
    public String peekFront() {
        return queArray[front];
    }

    /**
     * determines if the queue is empty
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (nItems == 0);
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the queue is full
     */
    public boolean isFull() {
        return (nItems == maxSize);
    }

    /**
     * determines size of queue
     */
    public int size() {
        return nItems;
    }

    public void display()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i< nItems; i++)
            System.out.println(queArray[(front+i) % maxSize]);
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private int age;
    private String email;
    private String education;
    private String experience;

    public ApplicationList(String lastName, String firstName, int age, String email, String education, String experience)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
        this.education = education;
        this.experience = experience;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEducation() {
        return education;
    }

    public void setEducation(String education) {
        this.education = education;
    }

    public String getExperience() {
        return experience;
    }

    public void setExperience(String experience) {
        this.experience = experience;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Applicant: Last Name: " + lastName + " ||| " +"First Name: " + firstName +" ||| " + " Email: " + email +" ||| " + " Age: " + age +" ||| " + 
                " Education: " + education +" ||| " + " Experience: " + experience;
    }

    static List<String> definedOrder = Arrays.asList("4+ years","2 years","Diploma","GED","NA");
    static Comparator<ApplicationList> EducationComparator= new Comparator<ApplicationList>() {
        public int compare(ApplicationList e1, ApplicationList e2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(definedOrder.indexOf(e1.getEducation())).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(e2.getEducation()));
        }
    };

    static class AgeComparator implements Comparator<ApplicationList> {
        public int compare(ApplicationList p1, ApplicationList p2) {
            int age1 = p1.getAge();
            int age2 = p2.getAge();

            if (age1 == age2)
                return 0;
            else if (age1 > age2)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
        }
    }

    public int compareTo(ApplicationList n) {
        return getLastName().compareTo(n.getLastName());
    }
}
```

Here is the driver, which is the one that is causing the problem:

**ApplicationDriver.Java;**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class ApplicationDriver
{
    public static <T> void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ApplicationList Applicants = new ApplicationList(5);

        ApplicationList sSmith = new ApplicationList("Smith", "Steve", 34, "SSmith@work.email", "GED", "Did a review on other games, hoping to review yours as well." );
        ApplicationList jRosen = new ApplicationList("Rosen", "Jane", 23, "RosenWall@zmail.com", "4+ years", "Game reviewing was somthing I've always wanted to try." );
        ApplicationList hAbhul = new ApplicationList("Abhul", "Habib", 19, "SwimminIndian@LookIn.org", "NA", "I like playing games, and feel like I have good insight." );
        ApplicationList aJones = new ApplicationList("Jones", "Abigail",27, "Jonsin4Love@zmail.com", "2 years", "I went to school for journalism, and think that I can write a fair and honest review of your games." );
        ApplicationList gInsider = new ApplicationList("Insider", "Gaming",0, "Michael@G.Insider.com", "Diploma", "Hi there, I am Michael from Gaming Insider. I see you are an upcoming developer, and want to see what you can do." );

        Applicants.enqueue(sSmith.toString());
        Applicants.enqueue(jRosen.toString());
        Applicants.enqueue(hAbhul.toString());
        Applicants.enqueue(aJones.toString());
        Applicants.enqueue(gInsider.toString());

        boolean success;

        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Enter the first letter of ");
            System.out.print("display, sort, remove: ");
            int choice = getChar();
            switch(choice) {
                case 'd':
                    Applicants.display();
                    break;
                case 's':
                    System.out.print("Enter the first letter to sort by ");
                    System.out.print("name, age, education: ");
                    int select = getChar();
                case 'e':
                    Collections.sort(Applicants, ApplicationList.EducationComparator);
                    Applicants.display();
                    break;
                case 'a':
                    Collections.sort(Applicants, new ApplicationList.AgeComparator());
                    Applicants.display();
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    Collections.sort(Applicants);
                    Applicants.display();
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    Applicants.dequeue();
                    Applicants.display();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Entry, retry\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public static String getString() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String s = br.readLine();
        return s;
    }

    public static char getChar() throws IOException {
        String s = getString();
        return s.charAt(0);
    }

    public static int getInt() throws IOException {
        String s = getString();
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
}
```

The Collections.sort is where my problems lie. What do I do to go about fixing my issues? If you need any more information, please ask!
Thanks for any and all help you are willing to give, and I apologize if my formatting for the website is horrible, I tried my best with it.

Thank you again for the assistance!

Aaron

Comment: `ApplicationList` does not implement `List`.  That's what it's complaining about.  How to fix it depends on the problem you are really trying to solve.

Comment: What I am trying to do is make it so when the user goes to sort by age, education, or by name that they can do so. But, with the code the way it is, it doesn't work.

How would I go about implementing the List without having to restructure my code?

Comment: @AaronFox You must restructure your code. At least make the type of `queArray` be `ApplicationList[]`. That way you can store a bunch of `ApplicationList` objects instead of their string representation. This allows you to get their age, name etc easily.

Answer (score 3):

You are violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

`ApplicationList` seems to represent two things:

- a list of applicants
- an applicant

Those two ideas are very distinct. You should create a class for each of them. To represent a list of applicants, you have a class called `ApplicationList`, and to represent one individual applicant, make a class called `Applicant`. Move all the fields and methods related to the applicant to the `Applicant` class (the age, name, email etc, and the constructor taking these parameters...). And then you can change `queArray`'s type to `Applicant[]`.

Your `Collection.sort` does not work because `ApplicationList` does not implement `Collection`.

Now, you need to implement the [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface in order for the `ApplicationList` to be sorted with `Collection.sort`. The interface has quite a few methods but they should be easy to implement.

Alternatively, you can just call `Arrays.sort` and sort the `queArray` instead.

Comment: Alright, so I have separated the larger class into two smaller classes, ApplicationList and Applicant. My biggest issue right now is that I cannot figure out how to implement the Collection interface. While trying to get it to work, I managed to get it to display the original list, but not the list after it is sorted.

Comment: @AaronFox you don't have to implement `Collection`. You can use `Arrays.sort` to sort your `queArray`